# Reduce a SQL Select based on Duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I've been racking my brain trying to come up with a solution for this, perhaps someone out there will find this an intriguing problem...

I've got a view:

```
[RecordID] [Status] [IsActive] [Company]
25791      NEW      Active      McDonalds
25792      NEW      Terminated  Rabble
25792      NEW      Active      Aetna
```

There are two cases

1. Only one record ID -- Simply return the record
2. Up to four records with the same ID -- IsActive and Company = 'Multiple'

This reduction must occur on a dataset of close to a million records.  Here's the output I'm looking for:

```
[RecordID] [Status] [IsActive] [Company]
25791      NEW       Active     McDonalds
25792      NEW       Multiple   Multiple
```

How do I select a row, but select a summary row when there is more then one record ID?

Comment: Hey there, what do you mean by "summary row"? I'm not sure I understand the question but I think I can help.

Comment: @DrewT A summary row simply meaning that for each of the RecordID's we only have one output row (With Multiple).  

25792 on the example above is what I think of as a summary row -- one row that represents multiple rows in the database.  Thanks for your help

Comment: Oh okay, so you do need to know when there are duplicates being reduced let me edit my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this would work:

```
SELECT 
    RecordID
    ,MAX(Status)
    ,CASE WHEN COUNT(IsActive) > 1
        THEN 'Multiple'
        ELSE MAX(IsActive)
        END
    ,CASE WHEN COUNT(Company) > 1
        THEN 'Multiple'
        ELSE MAX(Company)
        END
FROM [Table_1]
GROUP BY RecordID
```

[image: Query]

Comment: Seems 'hackish' but it's much better now :).

Comment: I have no idea why that works, but I'm seeing it on my end as well.  Fantastic answer!

Comment: @Aardvark It works because `MAX` is an aggregate function and without it the compiler will complain about `IsActive` and `Company` not being in an aggregate function or in the `GROUP BY` clause because `COUNT` is being used.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly I think you just want `DISTINCT` results:

```
SELECT DISTINCT RecordID, Status, IsActive
FROM table_name
WHERE IsActive = "$value"
```

More on `DISTINCT` here: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp

//EDIT:

The above will get your reduced result set but since you need to know if the `DISTINCT` is being triggered you probably also need to run a secondary count query on the RecordID you get in the above query to know if you need to display "multiple"

```
SELECT COUNT(RecordID)
FROM table_name
WHERE RecordID = "$RecordID_From_Other_Query"
```

Comment: Distinct alone won't do it alone.  We've got to alter that row to say Multiple in the event there is more then one record (which distinct just quietly filters out), distinct also won't work unless we exclude [IsActive] and [Company] from the group by in order for distinct to recognize those are repeated rows

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want. You GROUP the RecordID (only 1 occurence) and then put in Multiple for IsActive and Company if the count is bigger than 1, otherwise it's the field itself.

```
SELECT RecordID, Status, IF(COUNT(RecordID)>1,'Multiple',IsActive) as 'IsActive',IF(COUNT(RecordID)>1,'Multiple',Company) as 'Company' 
    FROM table 
    WHERE 1 
    GROUP BY RecordID
```

Comment: You are allowed to use an IF statement in a SELECT query?

Comment: You're allowed to have a column in the select without grouping by it?

Comment: No, it would need to be a `CASE` statement.  The code above is a syntax error.  Also, `WHERE 1` is not valid either.

Comment: Ah this is not MySQL? Sorry guys, but it would work there :/

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
SELECT 
RecordID,
MAX(Status) As Status,
CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 1 THEN 'Multiple' ELSE MAX(IsActive) END As IsActive,
CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 1 THEN 'Multiple' ELSE MAX(Company) END As Company
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY RecordID
```

What if there's more than four?

What do you want to do if there are different Status?

Answer (score 0):

This will work if you have more than one 'Status', using a CTE or it could be a temporary table, where you do the count of status column:

```sql
;with tblCount(ID, Sts, [Count])
as(
    select RecordId, Status, count(Status)
    from #tblTest  -- Whatever table name
    group by RecordId, Status
    )
    select distinct 
        RecordId, 
        Status, 
        case 
            when [count] > 1 then 'Multiple' 
            else IsActive
        end, 
        case
            when [count] > 1 then 'Multiple' 
            else Company
        end
    from tblCount t
    inner join #tblTest test on ID = RecordId
                                and Status = Sts
```

[image: Test Data]